# Automatically copy files to a flash drive in terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, catalina, script

I am trying to make a script that will automatically copy any files in the home directory with the extension .txt. What commands should I use in Terminal to search for and copy any txt files to a thumb drive?
Thanks

Comment: The `rsync` tool is made for this. Why make a script? ( which is a suggestion to show us your work or clarify with an edit what step you’re stuck on )

Comment: the goal of this project is to add it to a raspberry pi running p4wnp1

Comment: I got it working with rsync. Thanks for telling me about it

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. If you answer what you learned, it will get you some votes and help others. So glad you’re off and running. Pi are so much fun and very powerful tools.